# How do I round these 2 columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding

So I have searched on stack overflow and tried different solutions but I am not able to round these values.

This is the code

```
# Importing libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('/Users/What my username is/Documents/Coding/data/Data.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values


# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
x[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])
print(x)
```

The result I get is

```
[['France' 44.0 72000.0]
 ['Spain' 27.0 48000.0]
 ['Germany' 30.0 54000.0]
 ['Spain' 38.0 61000.0]
 ['Germany' 40.0 63777.77777777778]
 ['France' 35.0 58000.0]
 ['Spain' 38.77777777777778 52000.0]
 ['France' 48.0 79000.0]
 ['Germany' 50.0 83000.0]
 ['France' 37.0 67000.0]]
```

How would I round these values? Could I not just round the two rows with numerics in them?

I forgot to add but this is what Data.csv is

```
[['France' 44.0 72000.0]
 ['Spain' 27.0 48000.0]
 ['Germany' 30.0 54000.0]
 ['Spain' 38.0 61000.0]
 ['Germany' 40.0 nan]
 ['France' 35.0 58000.0]
 ['Spain' nan 52000.0]
 ['France' 48.0 79000.0]
 ['Germany' 50.0 83000.0]
 ['France' 37.0 67000.0]]
```

Comment: Sorry I wanted to add that I want to round them to be integers, so 0 decimal places.

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: A sample of Data.csv would be helpful.

Comment: Isn't this just `x[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3]).astype(int)` ?

Comment: @HenryEcker The problem with that is it rounds the 63777.7 down to 63777 when it should be 63778. Is there a fix for this or is this just something I have to deal with?

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the list that you get in your example. I will showan example with little change (adding coma):

```
lst =  [['France', 44.0, 72000.0],
['Spain', 27.0, 48000.0],
['Germany', 30.0, 54000.0],
['Spain', 38.0, 61000.0],
['Germany', 40.0, 0],
['France', 35.0, 58000.0],
['Spain', 0, 52000.0],
['France', 48.0, 79000.0],
['Germany', 50.0, 83000.0],
['France', 37.0, 67000.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
        0     1        2
0   France  44.0  72000.0
1    Spain  27.0  48000.0
2  Germany  30.0  54000.0
3    Spain  38.0  61000.0
4  Germany  40.0      0
5   France  35.0  58000.0
6    Spain   0  52000.0
7   France  48.0  79000.0
8  Germany  50.0  83000.0
9   France  37.0  67000.0

df[1] = df[1].astype(int)
df[2] = df[2].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

round the values first as a dataframe before grabbing values

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['France', 'Spain','Germany'],
                    'values': [40.332,67.3242,560.2334]})
df['values'].round()
```

Results

```
0     40.0
1     67.0
2    560.0
```